# Error al implementar aplicación de windows form con base de datos local

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, entity-framework-6

Tengo una aplicación en windows form, la cual pretendo que tenga una base de datos local, ya que es necesario que trabaje en ambientes offline, las pruebas se realizan correctamente, pero una vez que la aplicación es instalada en el equipo de computo destino, me tira el siguiente error:

> Expansion of |Data Directory| failed while processing the connection string. Ensure that |Data Directory| is set to a valid fully-qualified path.

En mi App.Config, defino el `connectionstring` de la siguiente manera:

```
<add name="ChecadorDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Datos\CHECADOR.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

En la clase del Entity Framework tengo lo siguiente:

```
namespace ALBATROS_WF.Conexion
{
    class AlbatrosCtxWF:DbContext
    {
        // Database.SetInitializer evita que Entity Framework cree las tablas automaticamente
        public AlbatrosCtxWF() : base("ChecadorDB") { Database.SetInitializer<AlbatrosCtx>(null); }

        //La Convencion de nombres pluralizados es eliminado  
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<UsuarioWF> UsuarioWFDB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AsistenciaWF> AsistenciaWFDB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entiendo que el error, me dice que necesita una "Ruta Completa" para poder acceder a mi base de datos, pero no se como darle solución, pues las rutas en desarrollo vs producción serán completamente diferentes.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El problema se soluciona declarando el 'DataDirectory' cuando arranca la aplicación. Por ejemplo:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

Comment: Este fragmento lo añado a la clase program?

Comment: Si, por ejemplo justo antes de arrancar la aplicación llamando a la función `.Run()`